# How to Cache css/js in one file and call that file from cache folder?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cache css and js in cache folder and call css from that folder is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587376/cache-css-and-js-in-cache-folder-and-call-css-from-that-folder-is-it-possible)

How to Cache css/js in one file and call that file from cache folder?
like css"http://http ref/css.r235436346.css"

Comment: I would take a look at the Minify Project, that does just this: http://code.google.com/p/minify/

Comment: Things are cached client-side for you automatically, if you're sending the right headers.

Comment: Hmm i need something that my simple cms look professional cms,the all site css filder cache in one file and call from cache folder like
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/cache/css.$time.css" type="text/css"/>

Comment: Google's mod_pagespeed for Apache is great for that and much more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to .htaccess file

```
<FilesMatch "main.css">
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .css
Header Set Content-Type "text/css"
</FilesMatch> 



<?php
$last_modified = date("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", filemtime("<name of the css file>"));
$expiration = date("D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T", strtotime('+1 year'));

 header("Cache-Control: public, no-transform");  
 header("Expires: $expiration");
 header("Last-Modified: $last_modified");
 ?>
```

i think same solution works for the js.

ref. from some thread on here but cant find link. been using it it works.

Comment: Hmm i need something that my simple cms look professional cms,the all site css filder cache in one file and call from cache folder like
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/cahe/css.$time.css" type="text/css"/>